# Multiple Clients in UDP server

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I wrote this code to recive data from a client via socket

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPServer
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(12890);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            while(true)
               {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                  InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                  int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                  String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                  sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                  DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                  new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                  serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
               }
      }
}
```

But if I try to launch another Client it don't work , look like if the server is blocked. How can I change the code to let the server communicating with more then one client

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a concurrent server. A concurrent server basically creates a child process for each client. Here is a basic way to do in java http://www.how2java.com/2012/05/how-to-create-concurrent-server-using.html